# rails runner jobs not releasing file log handles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I am running a rails runner job that sends out some emails based on database contents. The job runs every four hours via cron.

I realized this is causing a problem on our app server b/c the runner job holds onto some file log handles (production.log, etc) and the nightly logrotate job then fails. This causes disk space to fill up, etc.

The runner jobs invoke the Rails production environment, does a couple of ActiveRecord queries, sends an email via ActionMailer, and then exits. I'm not explicitly doing anything with the logs.

Is there something I can do inside the runner script to release log handles, or disable logging altogether (would rather not do the latter)? And should I be killing off the production Rails runner process formally? The script just ends ... but sometimes we see items like this in our processlist after the job has run:

4 S 1000     12008 12002  0  80   0 - 127507 futex_ Sep29 ?       00:00:32 ruby /path/to/my/app/rails runner -e production require 'delayed/command';Delayed::Worker.before_fork;Delayed::Command.new([]).run

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is in to change the log level for your environment file.

```
config.log_level = :fatal
```

Your environment file would be:

```
config/environments/production.rb
```

HOWEVER, you want it to run in production environment and doing this would turn off logs almost completely in production. (I know this you would not want)

So, you can define your own custom environment file say:

```
config/environments/my_custom_environment.rb
```

which is a complete clone to the production environment file except the log level. Also you will need to add a database.yml entry for the my_custom_environment database, same as your production database.yml entry. Search on internet on how to setup your own environment in rails for more details.

And then finally, instead of running your runner script in production environment you should run it in my_custom_environment.

Well, this is not a perfect solution to this problem (i guess there must be some more efficient and DRY way of doing this), but if nothing works out, this is the workaround you can try out.

Hope it helps :)